# How to combine unallocated partitons in dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-10, gparted, unallocated

[image: disk partiton]

I want to combine both the unallocated space. But I am getting the warning `Your system might not boot`

I am using `Windows 10` with `ubuntu 20.04`

I tried it in windows 10 using `AOMEI assistant` which was not even able to identify ubuntu partition and combined the 300gb(sda2) and 190gb  with "unallocated" tag!!

Anybody got any method for this??

Comment: What do you want to do with the unallocated space?

Comment: Combining the two into one partition be very hard to do with possible lost of data.  Can add the first one to sda2 easy using gparted on a USB stick(installer).  The second one should be done with Windows tools.  Could also back up all data you want to keep, and reinstall system to have partitions the way you want.

Comment: sda4 and 5 are data partitions. Make sure your backups are up to data and delete these partitions. You then will have all contiguous unallocated space which you then can partition to your liking.

Comment: @vanadium  Unless he has Win 10 on another drive, sda4 is probably his Win 10 partition.  sda5 also probably a partition important for Win 10, so deleting those two would cause to need a reinstall of Win 10.  Win 10 partitions usually labelled as Basic or Dynamic.

Comment: I woundn't try to move the Windows partitions as this might break Windows or Windows recovery. However, you could format the unallocated spaces as separate partitions and use them for whatever purpose you wish.

Comment: sda4 is windows C drive and sda5 is just to store some data